# How do I fix my package state after the installation process (dpkg) was interrupted?

Tags: dpkg, updates

I got the following message when I tried to open update.

> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must
>   manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure
>   -a' to correct the problem.
>   E: _cache->open() failed, please report.

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: did you run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'?

Answer (score 5):

Run the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` in terminal, just like the error message says to do.